# Unable to boot kernel and rootfile system in Qemu

Tags: debian, qemu, arm, cross-compilation

I am using ts-4900 freescale board. I am not able to boot the kernel and rootfile system (initrd) in Qemu. I did the following kernel configuration steps.

1. export the cross compiler parth
2. export LOADADDR=0x10008000
3. make esse_defconfig
4. make menuconfig ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
5. make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- uImage

The image is in `/arch/arm/boot/uImage`, and and I have working rootfile system (initrd).

Now i am trying to boot in Qemu using bellow step.

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -cpu cortex-a9 -kernel uImage -initrd /home/mahesh/mahesh/ts_4900/initrd.
```

then the error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The vexpress-a9 board doesn't have RAM at the 0x10008000 address, so when your kernel tries to run there it can't.

More generally, it looks like you're trying to build a kernel for one Arm board, and then run it with a QEMU model of a different Arm board. This does not work. You have to configure the kernel correctly for the hardware you're going to run it on, including if you're using emulated hardware. Otherwise the kernel will typically crash immediately without any output (since it won't be able to even find the serial port).